# PL/SQL dynamic row printing?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm a newbie in SQL and I was wondering if you can print the contents of a `cursor%rowtype` dynamically ?

For example:

```
cursor cur is select * from ...;

current_row cur%rowtype;

begin

open cur;

loop 

      fetch cur into current_row;

      -- dbms_output.put_line( current_row ); Would that be possible ?

      exit when cur%notfound;
 end loop;
```

Or do I have to do the boring part myself, that is specifying each member I need to print, which is quite lousy and lame, e.g.:

```
dbms_output.get_line( current_row.first || current_row.second || .... || current_row.last );
```

Is there a simple way to achieve dynamic printing to some extent in PL/SQL? Im using PL/SQL developer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DBMS_SQL package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm) to archive that. Of course it takes more lines (than the simple %rowtype cursor loop in your example) to create and loop through the cursor, but once this is done, you can process any SELECT query and output the results, no matter how many columns the query returns of what types the columns have.